# How to implement 'add to favorites'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on an exam project about sharing cooking recipes. I'm trying to implement "add to favorites" but I'm not having any success.

models.py

```
class FavoriteRecipeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1, 'Rating must be equal or greater than 1'),
            MaxValueValidator(5, 'Rating must be equal or less than 5'),
        ]
    )
```

forms.py

```
class AddToFavoriteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteRecipeModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class AddToFavoritesView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Recipe
    form_class = AddToFavoriteForm
    template_name = 'recipes/recipe-details.html'
    context_object_name = 'add_to_favorites'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        recipe_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        user = request.user

        # Check if the recipe is already in favorites
        if FavoriteRecipeModel.objects.filter(user=user, recipe__pk=recipe_pk).exists():
            # Recipe is already in favorites, handle as needed
            pass
        else:
            # Recipe is not in favorites, add it
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=recipe_pk)
            favorite = FavoriteRecipeModel(user=user, recipe=recipe)
            favorite.save()

        return redirect('recipe_details', pk=recipe_pk, slug=recipe.slug)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('all-recipes/', AllRecipeListView.as_view(), name='all recipes'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search results'),
    path('add-recipe/', CreateRecipeView.as_view(), name='add recipe'),
    path('my-recipes/<int:pk>/', MyRecipesView.as_view(), name='my recipes'),
    path('my-recipe-details/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', MyRecipesDetailsView.as_view(),
         name='my recipe details'),
    # path('my-favorites/add/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', AddToFavoritesView.as_view(), name='add to favorites'),
    path('my-favorites/<int:pk>/', FavoriteListView.as_view(), name='favorite recipes'),
    path('category/<str:category>/', RecipeByCategoryView.as_view(), name='recipe by category'),
    path('details/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', RecipesDetailsView.as_view(), name='recipe details'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', EditRecipeView.as_view(), name='edit recipe'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', RecipeDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete recipe'),
]
```

template

```
{% extends 'common/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ recipe.title }}</h1>
        <p><strong>Category:</strong> {{ recipe.get_category_display }}</p>
        {% if recipe.image_url %}
            <img src="{{ recipe.image_url }}" alt="static/images/no-image-available.lpeg" style="max-width: 300px;">
        {% endif %}
        <p>Created by: {{ recipe.created_by }}</p>
        <p>Created at: {{ recipe.created_at }}</p>
        <p>Last updated at: {{ recipe.updated_at }}</p>

        <h2>Ingredients</h2>
        <div>
            <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: keep-all;">{{ recipe.ingredients }}</pre>
        </div>
        <h2>Instructions</h2>
        <div>
            <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: keep-all;">{{ recipe.instructions }}</pre>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'recipe details' recipe.pk recipe.slug %}">
                {{ add_to_favorites }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to My Favorites</button>
                {% csrf_token %}
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            {% for comment in recipe.commentsmodel_set.all %}
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <p><strong>{% firstof comment.user.profile.get_full_name comment.user.username %}</strong></p>
                    <pre>{{ comment.text }}</pre>
                    <span>{{ comment.published_date }}</span>
                </div>
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <div>
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'recipe details' recipe.pk recipe.slug %}">
                    {{ comment_form.text|as_crispy_field }}
                    <button class="btn" type="submit">Post comment</button>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div>
                <p>You need to <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> to post a comment</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
        <div class="col-4">
            {% if request.user.is_staff %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'edit recipe' recipe.pk recipe.slug %}">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="{% url 'delete recipe' recipe.pk recipe.slug %}">Delete</a>
            {% endif %}
            <input class="btn" type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back()">
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The idea is that when you go to the recipe details page, there will be an "add to favorites" button. When I click on the button, the page is simply refreshed and nothing is saved in the database.